# How to add cell to a UITableView on another ViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have an app which contains a listing of businesses. I also have a UITableView on another ViewController which holds a list of the users favourites. When the user hits the 'add to favourites' button, I want a cell to be added to the TableView containing the business' name. I have figured out how to add it to the TableView if the 'add to favourites button' and TableView are on the same ViewController but not if they are on separate ViewControllers. When they are separate, I hit the 'add to favourites button' and nothing happens. Although they are seperate ViewControllers they have the same class. Here is how I have tried to implement the IBAction for the 'add to favourites button':

```
- (IBAction)addFav:(id)sender {
[tableView1 beginUpdates];
[favourites addObject:@"New Business"];
NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:([favourites count] - 1) inSection:0];
[self.tableView1 insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
[tableView1 endUpdates];
[tableView1 reloadData];
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Reload the table view on view will appear

Comment: ViewControllers have the same class... What do you mean here?
Also, are you familiar with target-action Design pattern in iOS?

Comment: you need to pass array to next class. like this favoritesViewController.favoritesArray = countries;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass array reference to next view controller. In next VC add object to same array. Then when you come back call table reload from viewWillAppear method.

Comment: Hi Durgaprasad
I have called next view controller FavViewController. I am trying to add the code

Comment: Hi Durgaprasad
I have called next view controller FavViewController.

 I am trying to add the code 'FavViewController.favArray = favourites;' to HomeViewController.m in super viewdidload:

When I do this xcode tells me 'Property 'favArray' not fount on object of type 'FavViewController'.
  I have declared favArray in FavViewController.h as:
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray * favArray;

Where in HomeViewController.m should i be adding FavViewController.favArray = favourites;?